# PC flooding & crashing network switch only after it's shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-8, network-adapter, windows-8.1

I discovered this problem because EVERY SINGLE TIME I left the house my Internet connection would go down and I would not be able to remotely access my netowrk.

I installed Windows 8.1 RTM on my Rampage Forumula. It has Marvell Yukon 88E8056 NICs and the latest drivers from Windows Update.

Whenever I shutdown my computer now it takes several minutes for the motherboard lights to power off even after all the other devices have shutdown. After it shuts down, the NIC lights start blinking rapidly and within a few minutes my entire network switch crashes and the LAN goes down.

This only happens on the NIC that was plugged in while the computer was shut down. While the computer is off, if I plug the cable into the second NIC, the LEDs simply come on like Wake-on-LAN. If I plug it back into the first NIC the LEDs blink rapidly and it floods the network again.

When I switch the PC on again, once the Windows kernel starts and loads the drivers it starts functioning normally again.

Comment: Have you tried using the driver provided by Asus instead of the generic driver from Microsoft?

Comment: Its a worth of try to see if the problem exists in that version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This no longer happens with the latest drivers. However I did find out that it was due to the Windows 8 fast shutdown / boot feature. Disabling that caused the NIC to stop malfunctioning at the time.

Comment: Can you add varsion numbers to your answer, it would be more helpfull is you say what versions give problems, and what versions aren't conflicting